# Write a program that asks the user for a month number and displays the number of days that month has (putting a leap year in mind)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't quite understand why my code doesn't work and for Year 1900 (Not a leap year), it still displays 29 days

```
    Dim Month, Year As Integer
    Dim X, Y As Single

    Console.WriteLine("Which month is it?")
    Month = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Which year is it?")
    Year = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case Month
        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
            Console.WriteLine("Number of days is 30.")
        Case 2
            If Year Mod 100 = 0 Then
                X = Year Mod 400
            Else
                Y = Year Mod 4
            End If
            If X = 0 Or Y = 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("The number of days is 29.")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("The number of Days is 28.")
            End If
        Case Else
            Console.WriteLine("Number of days is 31")
    End Select
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Are you sure it works at all for non-leap years? Because it appears that you'll only ever set `X` *or* `Y` and so one of them *should* always be `0`.

Comment: It always gives "29" as the answer.
Even if X=0 or Y=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd get rid of `X` and `Y` - as I said in a comment, *one* of them will always be equal to zero since your code only ever changes *one* of them. Whilst you *could* make both branches of your `If` about the 100 years rule set the *same* variable and then check it for `0`, I'd just put all of the logic directly in a single `If`:

```
If Year Mod 400 = 0 Or (Year Mod 4 = 0 And Not Year Mod 100 = 0) Then
    Console.WriteLine("The number of days is 29.")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("The number of Days is 28.")
End If
```